# Specifying Whitespace Only option for UglifyJS2

Tags: bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs, gruntjs, uglifyjs2

I am trying to use grunt for minifying javascript files in a project using UglifyJS2.

Does UglifyJS2 have any options like WHITESPACE_ONLY ( which exists in Closure Compiler)?

What are the values do I have to pass in options node in GruntFile.js for that effect?

```
uglify: {
        options: {
            mangle: { toplevel: false },
            squeeze: { dead_code: false }
        },
        'dist': {
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: '**/*.js'
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there an answer for this?